# NLP in non-english languages possible?

Tags: natural-language

I would like to use Mathematica NLP functions to analyze texts in French. I haven’t found any documentation on how good it will be compared to english (and if it’s even possible to use non-english languages).

For instance, I have just tried:

```
moon = WikipediaData["Lune", Language -> "French"];
contents = TextContents[moon, VerifyInterpretation -> True]
```

and got the error message `NaturalLanguageProcessingTextTokenize::liberr: -- Message text not found -- (Java) (MathLinkException: 49: Unable to convert from MathLink encoding to requested character encoding)`

Is this just an encoding problem or a more general problem related to using non-english languages?

Comment: This seems like a bug in `TextContents`. It may not work with other languages, but a character encoding issue is not the way you should find out! I would recommend submitting a bug report.

Comment: @CarlLange I will. Any idea about is Mathematica good for doing NLP in non-english language?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience of using `TextContents` with different languages, though it appears to function at least a little bit.